# Zero point energy and volume integral of the expected value of intensity

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum

In his article "The concept of the photon" Scully and Sargent say that the zero point energy of the quantized electromagnetic field $\hbar\omega/2$ is given by the volume integral of $\langle 0|E^2|0\rangle$.

I wonder if this is the reason.

Since the electromagnetic energy density is 
\begin{equation}
u=\epsilon_0 \mathbf{E}^2\,,
\end{equation}
then

\begin{align}\label{key}
E&=\epsilon_0\int\langle 0|E^2|0\rangle dV\,\\
&=\epsilon_0\int\frac{\hbar\omega}{\epsilon_0 V}\sin^2(kz)\,dV\,,\\
&=\frac{\hbar\omega}{A\cdot L}\int_{0}^{L}\sin^2(kz)\,A\,dz\,,\\
 &=\frac{\hbar\omega}{L}\cdot\frac{1}{2}L\,,\qquad\text{Boundary conditions within the quantized cavity, $ \sin(kL)=0 $}\,,\\
&=\frac{\hbar\omega}{2}\,.
\end{align}

I don't know if this is correct because I've been trying to find any other authors who state the same without success. **Please provide some reference of some authors stating this if possible.**

Also, does this mean that the expected value of the intensity is a kind of energy density? which suggests that the energy of the vacuum fluctuates around the value $\hbar\omega/2$